# C# - Accessing Javascript modified HTML via a Console app

Tags: c#, javascript, html, browser

I am attempting to access the HTML of a page after it has been modified by the JavaScripts on the page.  This is what I have been currently attempting based on what I have found online.

```
using System; 
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO; 

namespace WebBrowserDemo 
{ 
    class Program 
    {
    public const string TestUrl = @"http://www.theverge.com/2012/7/2/3126604/android-jelly-bean-updates-htc-samsung-google-pdk"; 

    [STAThread] 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser(); 
        wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted); 
        wb.Navigate(TestUrl); 

        while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) 
        { 
            Application.DoEvents(); 
        } 

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue..."); 
        Console.ReadKey(true); 
    } 

    static void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender; 

        HtmlElement document = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0];

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("OuterHTML.txt"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(document.OuterHtml);
        }

        var abc = wb.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);" });

        Console.WriteLine();
        document = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0];

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("OuterHTML2.txt"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(document.OuterHtml);
        }

    } 
} 
}
```

The ultimate goal is to scroll to the bottom of the page activating any JS to load the comments on the article. Though currently the html I get back from before and after the script is ran is the same.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Even if this is possible, it would seem highly unreliable. Do you have access to the web site code? Can you add a web service and call it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it with [a WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This is basically a componentized version of IE.  Load the page into the control.  You probably do not even need to display the page.  You can register an event handler that will be called when the page is fully loaded.  There is no definite way to determine when the scripts have  "completed" - scripts are open-ended and may run as long as they like.  So you'd have to build in a heuristic "Wait period", then examine the HTML after that wait period passes.

Incidentally this is exactly what [IECapt](http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/) does.